# JQuery $(window).resize() function is not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm new here, I got here after a series of search on this issue.
I have a jquery slider with a next/prev button... everything works fine excerpt I want to show a number of images based on the current browser width, eg if browser width is less than 400 show only 1 image and so on. This works on load however but when I resize the browser it doesn't work as expected. ( I am new to Jquery too..Obviously ). Please I will highly appreciate your help.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="trends">
    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>

    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>

    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>

    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>

    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>

    <div class="top-trends">
        <img src="/some-img.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var windowsWidth = $(window).width();

        if ( windowsWidth < 400 ) {
            $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(0)').hide();

            var slideFoward = function() {
                var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
                var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

                if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 1 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                    $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                next.show();
                first.hide();
            }
            var slideBackwards = function() {
                var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
                var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
                var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

                if ( hf == 1  ) {
                    $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                prev.show();
                last.hide();
            }
        }

        else if ( windowsWidth < 600 ) {
            $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(1)').hide();

            var slideFoward = function() {
                var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
                var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

                if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 2 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                    $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                next.show();
                first.hide();
            }
            var slideBackwards = function() {
                var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
                var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
                var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

                if ( hf == 2  ) {
                    $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                prev.show();
                last.hide();
            }
        }

        else if ( windowsWidth < 800 ) {
            $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(2)').hide();

            var slideFoward = function() {
                var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
                var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

                if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 3 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                    $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
                next.show();
                first.hide();
            }
            var slideBackwards = function() {
                var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
                var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
                var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 3  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }

    else {
        $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(3)').hide();

        var slideFoward = function() {
            var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
            var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

            if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 4 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            next.show();
            first.hide();
        }
        var slideBackwards = function() {
            var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
            var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
            var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 4  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }
    $('.trends-next').click(slideFoward);
    $('.trends-back').click(slideBackwards);
});


$(window).resize(function(){
    var windowsWidth = $(window).width();

    if ( windowsWidth < 400 ) {
        $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(0)').hide();

        var slideFoward = function() {
            var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
            var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

            if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 1 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            next.show();
            first.hide();
        }
        var slideBackwards = function() {
            var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
            var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
            var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 1  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }

    else if ( windowsWidth < 600 ) {
        $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(1)').hide();

        var slideFoward = function() {
            var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
            var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

            if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 2 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            next.show();
            first.hide();
        }
        var slideBackwards = function() {
            var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
            var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
            var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 2  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }

    else if ( windowsWidth < 800 ) {
        $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(2)').hide();

        var slideFoward = function() {
            var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
            var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

            if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 3 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            next.show();
            first.hide();
        }
        var slideBackwards = function() {
            var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
            var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
            var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 3  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }

    else {
        $('.trends').children('.top-trends:gt(3)').hide();

        var slideFoward = function() {
            var next = $('.top-trends:visible').next();
            var first = $('.top-trends:visible').first();

            if ( $('.top-trends:visible').length == 4 && $('.top-trends:visible ~ .top-trends:hidden').length == 0 ) {
                $('.trends-next').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            next.show();
            first.hide();
        }
        var slideBackwards = function() {
            var prev = $('.top-trends:visible').prev();
            var last = $('.top-trends:visible').last();
            var hf = $('.top-trends:visible').last().prevAll().length;

            if ( hf == 4  ) {
                $('.trends-back').addAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
            prev.show();
            last.hide();
        }
    }
    $('.trends-next').click(slideFoward);
    $('.trends-back').click(slideBackwards);
});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: "Doesn't work as expected" is not enough information.  How do you expect it to work and what do you observe the behavior of your current code to be?  Remember, we don't know what you want and you haven't given us anything we can run and look at so all we have to go on is your words and any intent we can discern from your code.  Please describe better exactly what you want and exactly what your current code is doing that is different than that.

Comment: P.S.  You should be able to factor into a common function the exact same code to be used at startup and upon resize rather than copying lots of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I think I know what you mean. The elements get hidden when deceasing the window size, but are not shown when increasing it, right?

If I got the problem well, it's a simple fix. You just want to show all the images on every window resize, and then make the decision which elements to hide:

`$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.trends').children('.top-trends').show();
    if (windowsWidth < 400) {
        ...`

See the whole thing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fh0frk1h/) (I got rid of all the slideFoward/slideFoward functions for clarity - you may want to remove all unnecessary code as well next time, it will make figuring the issue out much simpler).

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I wanted. lol all the hours I spent searching and it's only a one line fix :) Thanks a lot @wap300 you just made my day!